# Problems making a many-to-many relationship work across 2 microservices using Spring Boot & Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So for this assignment, I'm supposed to have 2 microservices (task-service & user-service) with each having their own database.
A task can have multiple users assigned it but multiple users can be assigned to multiple tasks so therefore it's a many-to-many relationship.

Both microservices are Spring Boot applications using Hibernate and I'm struggling to make this relationship happen between task and user inside the task-service because I don't think it's a good idea to copy the user model that already exists in the user-service, over to the task-service.

This assignment assumes that there is consistency in the user-ids across both databases without using foreign keys.

For context:

**Desired entity relationship diagram generated from Hibernate:**[image: ERD]

**Task.java [task-service]**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    private String name, description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Lane lane;

    @OneToMany
    private List<TaskUser> users;
}
```

**TaskUser.java [task-service]**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TaskUser {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "task_id")
    private Long taskId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
 }
```

**User.java [user-service]**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
}
```

Currently, Hibernate is generating both a task_user & task_users table inside the task-service database and I'd like to just have 1 intermediate table instead of two.

**Question**: How would I make this many-to-many relationship work with Hibernate whilst working with two different microservices?

Comment: What sort of tasks you need to perform? You may start from the business requirement like user-signup, login, task creation, task allocation etc. In all of this, user-module should not be having any dependency on task-service. Although, task service might connect to user-service for fetching user data. User db would not be having task details . Just create a column for user in task table in task-service

Comment: A task can have multiple users so a column on the task table wouldn't work I'm pretty sure. The call to the task-service would be done through the angular webapp and not the user-service by the way.

Comment: It's just how you perceive the approach. You can have an `allocation-table` with alloc-id  and `task-id`as pk(see embeddable ids), then associate multiple users(records) with same `task-id` and new `alloc-id` (auto-generate).

Comment: How would this look like in a Spring Boot Hibernate context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a better hibernate mapping :

Task.java [task-service]

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    private String name, description;

    @ManyToOne
    private Lane lane;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
    private List<TaskUser> users;
}
```

TaskUser.java [task-service]

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TaskUser {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="task_id", nullable=false)
    private Task task;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
 }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use case: assign an already existing task to an already existing user.
You can assign multiple users at a time to 1 single task.

###### PostRequest

`/tasks/allocation/new`

Request Body:

```json
    {
      "task-id": 12345,
      "users": [
        {
          "username": "user-1",
          "user-id": 101
        },
        {
          "username": "user-2",
          "user-id": 102
        },
        {
          "username": "user-3",
          "user-id": 103
        }
      ]
    }
```

Post request is having one task and list of user-details to be allocated to that task.

###### TaskAllocation.java

```
    @Data
    public class TaskAllocation{
     @jsonProperty("task-id")
     private long taskId;
     @JsonProperty("users")
     private List<Users> userList;
}
```

###### Users.java

```
    @Data
    public class Users{
     @jsonProperty("username")
     private String username;
     @JsonProperty("user-id")
     private Long userId;
}
```

###### RestController

```
    @PostMapping("/tasks/allocation/new")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> assignTaskToUsers(@ResponseBody @Valid TaskAllocation taskAllocation){

      // service call

    }
```

###### Inside service:

1. fetch the task from task db(verify if task exist)
2. If needed, fetch details of users from user-service(for each user), need a async or rest call to user-service. Task service is not having details of users.
3. For each user:
   1.Create new Allocation
4. Set task Id
5. Set user-id or username
6. Save

> Task is already existing

###### Table Task-Allocation

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    alloc-id(Pk)         task-Id(Fk)        user-id    timetamp     
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    1                     12345         101         123123123123
    2                     12345         102         123123123123
    3                     12345         103         123123123123
```

###### Entities

`Task` and `TaskAllocation` has 1:n relationship i.e. `task-allocation` table consists of multiple records with same `task-id`.

Task.java

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sirf_tournament")
    public class Task extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long taskId;

        private String taskName;
        
        // others
        
          @OneToMany(
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              mappedBy = "task",
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              orphanRemoval = true)
          private Collection<TaskAllocation> taskAllocation = new HashSet<>();

    }
```

TaskAllocation.java

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sirf_tournament")
    public class TaskAllocation extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long allocId;

        private Long userId;
        
        
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "taskId")
        private Task task;

        // others

    }
```

`User` table and other related entities are not mentioned here. Task service has no information of users.

It would be good if you verify every users(all ids can be verified in a single call, return invalid ids from user service) and task ids before persisting them into table.

Comment: I don't see any Hibernate annotations though?

Comment: Entities are all simple as with any other cases.  Let me update the answer.